# k8s with traefik: open udp port as ingress rule

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress, k3s

I've just deployed a k3d cluster.

I don't quite figure out how to open a udp port in order to build an ingress rule.

Traefik is used as ingress controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define an entryPoints as below. Use Traefik version 2.2.0-rc1

```
## Static configuration
entryPoints:
  streaming:
    address: ":1704/udp"
```

The UDP feature is limited by

1. No TLS for now, which means
2. No routing rule, since there is no criterion on which to match
   packets (there is no PathPrefix notion since there are no requests
   at the transport layer level, and no HostSNI since no TLS). Which
   means it's pretty much only load-balancing in one form or another at
   the moment.

Comment: UDP can be use with all the providers.